# Profilling results - how to understand

Tags: c#, profiling

I did profiling for my console application using Unity IOC and a lot of calls using HttpCLient. How to understand it?

**Function Name,   Inclusive Samples,   Exclusive Samples,  Inclusive Samples %, Exclusive Samples %**

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve                                    175 58  38.89   12.89
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer..ctor                                      29  29  6.44    6.44
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1[System.DateTime].Start      36  13  8.00    2.89
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterInstance                 9   9   2.00    2.00
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor                                             9   9   2.00    2.00
System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.Dispose                                          9   9   2.00    2.00
System.Activator.CreateInstance                                                     20  8   4.44    1.78
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve   115 3   25.56   0.67
```

What means that inclusive samples for `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve`     are `38,89` but exclusive are `12,89`? Is it ok? Not too much?

Answer (score 1):

"Inclusive" means "exclusive time plus time spent in all callees".
Forget the "exclusive" stuff.
"Inclusive" is what it's costing you.

It says `UnityContainer.Resolve` is costing you 39% of time,
and `Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve` is costing you 26%.
It looks like the first one calls the second one, so you can't add their times together.
If you could avoid calling all that stuff, you would save at least 40%, giving you a speedup of at least 100/60 or 1.67 or 67%

By the way, that Unity stuff, while not exactly deprecated, is no longer being maintained.